# One observer listening for two or more events

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

Is it possible for one custom observer to listen to more than one event?

I have a custom observer which right now is listening to only one event, I would like to add 1 or more events for that observer to listen to.

Is it possible or should I create a new observer for each event I want to listen?

Comment: I think you can filter with event name like $observer->getEvent()->getName(),

Comment: magento 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but i'd prefer serveral (observer) methods as long it should not do exactly the same.

```
<events>
    <event_one>
        <observers>
            <your_module_event_one>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>yourMethod</method>
            </your_module_event_one>
        </observers>
    </event_one>
    <event_two>
        <observers>
            <your_module_event_two>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>yourMethod</method>
            </your_module_event_two>
        </observers>
    </event_two>
</events>
```

Comment: Yes, the above works. I found that out just couple of minutes ago. But right now I actually need the methods to be the exact same/do the same thing. Basically at the moment I'm sending the selected/clicked product's data to somewhere, but I also need to do that when this is item is added to the cart or bought.

Comment: Well I found the solution for my problem. Just had to declare different events I want to listen in the config.xml file and keep everything else in the <observers> tag the same.

Comment: That is what i've posted above? ;)

Comment: Yes :) I have no idea how I couldn't notice that Your solution is exactly the same.